# checkedlistbox unseleted when unchecked any item

Tags: c#, .net

I want to select all option in checkedlistbox. Select all/Unselected all is working fine (code below) but i want to unselect select all option when any item is unchecked and select all when all items are selected.

this is code i worked on. This code is

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Index == 0 && e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
            {
                for (int it = 1; it < this.checkedListBox1.Items.Count; it++)
                {
                    this.checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(it, false);
                }
            }
            if (e.Index == 0 && e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                for (int it = 1; it < this.checkedListBox1.Items.Count; it++)
                {
                    this.checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(it, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: dear do you want select/unselect all the items below the checked item?

Comment: _"want to unselect select all option"_ ... _"select all when all items are selected"_ does that make sense?

Comment: when any item (not select all) will be checked or unchecked, there will be effect on select all option. select all means all items are selected but any item is unchecked that means all the items are not selected so select all option should be unchecked. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to select/unselect all the Items below the checked Item

Try This:

```
   private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
        {
            for (int it = e.Index+1; it < this.checkedListBox1.Items.Count; it++)
            {
                this.checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(it, false);
            }
        }
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            for (int it = e.Index+1; it < this.checkedListBox1.Items.Count; it++)
            {
                this.checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(it, true);
            }
        }
    }
```